# Laravel 5 multi language not working

Tags: laravel, localization

I tried to localization my app, but seems like I'm missing something.  I don't have any previous knowledge about this and therefore it's pretty hard to get started. Here is my routes.php

```
Route::get('/lang/{lang}', 'LangController@index');
```

And here is my LangController.php

```
 public function index($lang)

{
    $langs =['en', 'de'];
    if(in_array($lang, $langs)){
        Session:set('lang', $lang);
        return Redirect::back();
    }
}
```

I set in middleware:(Lang.php)

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)

{

    if($lang = Session::get('lang')){
        \Lang::setLocale($lang);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Enable it in Http\Kernel.php:

```
  protected $middleware = [

   \App\Http\Middleware\Lang::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

    ];
```

In my blade.php

```
 {{ Lang::get('home.hello')}}
   CURRENT: {{ Lang::getLocale() }} <br /> <br />
 <a href="{{ url('lang/de') }}">Germany</a> | <a href="{{ url('lang/en') }}">English</a>
```

Please help.I do not see what I missing...
In field CURRENT when press Germany it shoul be 'de' and when press English it shoul be 'en' but when press Germany it still stay 'en'... (default is 'en' config/app.php ->  'locale' => 'en',)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the session in your middleware, the values you need will not be available until the `StartSession` middleware sets up the session.

So you should add your middleware somewhere after that, like so:

```php
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, // Init session
    \App\Http\Middleware\Lang::class, // Set locale
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];
```

Aside from that you also have a small syntax error in your controller code. You forgot to add the second colon (`:`) for the scope resolution operator, when assigning the value to the session in your `index` controller method. So this:

```php
Session:set('lang', $lang);
```

Should be this:

```php
Session::set('lang', $lang);
```

Comment: What Laravel version are you using? 5.0, 5.1 or 5.2?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a second problem I've noticed with your code.