# Why is this syntax valid? "foo:;" (WordCharacters colon semi-colon)

Tags: php

I've answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223578/laravel-5-multi-language-not-working/35223722#35223722) today that had a simple solution, but I've yet to understand why it was something for which the PHP interpreter didn't throw a syntax error. So my question is simple:

**Why are the statements below considered to have valid syntax?**

```
SomeIdentifier:;
AnythingGoesApparently:;
ThisCanGoOnAndOn:;
```

Even more so since those identifiers are not defined anywhere.

---

To my knowledge the colon `:` is only used as part of two operators: [The Scope Resolution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php), [The Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), but not on its own. It's also used in the [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). But none of these would qualify in this case, so this is bugging me like crazy.

Comment: They are labels, used with `goto`.

Comment: It's also used as part of `switch/case`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe these would be interpreted as `goto` labels.

For example:

```
$x = 0;
goto ThisIsBad;
$x++;

ThisIsBad:
$x += 2;

echo $x;
```

Output: `2`

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php